# Samba Client and Windows 10 Home - "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE"/"Access denied"

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, samba, smb, smbclient

I'm trying to access a file share from a **Windows 10 Home** using a Samba client. However the following errors happen ...

**1# - smbclient**

```
[root@eduardo-nb eduardo]# smbclient -L 192.168.0.5 -W WORKGROUP -U eduardo
Enter WORKGROUP\eduardo's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

**2# - Dolphin**

[image: Access denied to smb://WORKGROUP%5Ceduardo@192.168.0.5/D.]

---

**NOTE:** The only way to gain access to the share is by following the procedures described here ...

[File Sharing not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-sharing-not-working/e6df6ac5-bb5a-41b3-8253-bd59b49d94bd)

... which consist of allowing access to "Everyone" and "Turn off password protected sharing".

**QUESTION:** I would like to access this share with my existing Windows 10 Home user (has administrative prerogatives)... **So what may be happening?**

Thanks! =D

[Refs.: https://askubuntu.com/q/47291/134723 , https://askubuntu.com/q/109507/134723 , https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-sharing-not-working/e6df6ac5-bb5a-41b3-8253-bd59b49d94bd , https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/samba-client-and-windows-10-home/a7502032-240a-4fc8-a756-132d46831adf?tm=1568998329476]

---

**UPDATE I:** My `/etc/samba/smb.conf` ...

@harrymc

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Samba Server
   allow insecure wide links = yes
   printcap name = /etc/printcap
   load printers = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 50
   security = user
   dns proxy = no

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   writable = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   path = /var/spool/samba
   browseable = no
   guest ok = no
   writable = no
   printable = yes

[eduardo]
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
   comment = Manjaro Linux Samba share
   path = /home/eduardo
   available = yes
   valid users = eduardo
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
   public = no
   writeable = yes
```

Comment: Your are using a backward slash, which got translated to `%5C`. This needs to be a forward slash. Also, you don't need the workgroup. https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/smb

Comment: What version of SMB are you using?

Comment: Tips.. Try dropping the -W WORKGROUP parameter..  If it still doesn't work, try adding the ip address of the machine name in front of the user name. <ipaddr>\\eduardo or <ipaddr>/eduardo.  try putting the windows ip for the -W <ipaddr>.. play with combinations of this and you will likely succeed.

Comment: @Ramhound "What version of SMB are you using?" -> Samba version 4! =D

Comment: @TuxStash.de "Your are using a backward slash, which got translated to %5C. This needs [...]" -> Didn't work... Thanks!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas "Tips.. Try dropping the -W WORKGROUP parameter.. If it still doesn't work [...]" -> Didn't work... Thanks!

Comment: Try using `smbclient -l` instead of `smbclient -L`. If this doesn't help, better post your `smb.conf`.

Comment: @harrymc See the update above. Thanks! =D

Comment: Does the account "eduardo" exist on the Windows 10 system?  Also note that on Windows, the "share" permissions are distinct and in addition to the normal file permissions.  Make sure both file and share permissions are set properly.

Comment: @LawrenceC "[...] \"eduardo\" exist on the Windows 10 system [...]" -> Yes! I use to log on Windows 10. "[...]\"share\" permissions are distinct and in addition to the normal file permissions [...]" -> The folder is shared and access to it is set to "Everyone" (with all possible permissions). Thanks! =D

Comment: I begin to suspect that there is some kind of incompatibility between the current version of Windows 10 and Samba 4 or Windows 10 Home is not able to share folders... =|

Comment: @EduardoLucio - Samba 4 isn't the SMB version.  What SMB version is Samba 4 configured to use?  You will have to do the proper amount of research to understand what I am asking for, and it absolutely is required, to properly answer your question.  **There is absolutely NOT an incompatibility with Windows 10 Home and Samba.  What you want is absolutely possible with Windows 10 Home.**  Instead of replying to every comment, update your question, with the information that is being requested.  The comment section currently is unnecessarily busy.

Comment: @Ramhound Done! =D

Comment: I get the impression that "superuser" is the community with the most downvoters on the internet despite the effort and donation of many of its participants... Sad... A comment or guidance is worth more than 1000 downvotes. =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio - Your last edit has made your question is unreadable.  Despite all the information you added to the question body, you still have not provided the one piece of information, the community must know to answer your question.  The one bit of information that is vital to solving your problem is to know what version of SMB, Samba 4, configured to support.  By default Windows 10 does not have SMB1 support enabled if Samba is configured to use the only SMBv1 that would be the reason for your problems.

Comment: The Samba log file also has additional information required to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound ´smbstatus´ -> "Samba version 4.10.6". Since the Samba version is 4 and I don't define anything about the SMB implementation version in `smb.conf`, so I think I'm using SMB4.

Comment: @EduardoLucio - SMB4 does not actually exist.  Once the information about which version of [SMB](https://serverfault.com/questions/895570/how-to-configure-samba-to-work-with-windows-10-1709) you have configured Samba to use exists in your question body (along with the relevant information from the Samba log), I will be able to answer your question.

Comment: The command `less +F /var/log/samba/log.smbd` don't show me new entries when I try to access the share on Windows 10.

Comment: That would be an indication that Windows not the Linux box is blocking the connection, attempting to use SMBv1 while it was disabled, would explain that behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not think so... The "SMB 1.0/CIFS Client", "SMB 1.0/CIFS Automatic Removal" and "SMB 1.0/CIFS Server" options are enabled in Windows 10 Home. The `server min protocol = SMB3` and `client min protocol = SMB3` parameters are in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Thanks! =P

Comment: @EduardoLucio - After 9 hours you finally answered my question, with regards to version of SMB, Samba 4 is configured to use.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm doing my best! =P

Comment: You have `security = user`, meaning that `eduardo` must be a *user account on the Samba server*. Is that the case and are you entering the right password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE REAL PROBLEM:**

As you can see in this image...

[image: share issue]

...my user "eduardo" is actually "alldocube"... As seen in the print above the way the user "eduardo" ("alldocube") is in the system caused a huge confusion! Actually I couldn't understand how it happened...

**SOLUTION:**

So the only thing that needs to be done is to share (Properties > Sharing) drive "D" for the user "alldocube" (in my case) and give permissions (Properties > Security) on drive "D" for the user "alldocube".

To access the sharing using Linux open the file browser (Dolphin in my case) and in the path field enter `smb://WORKGROUP\<YOUR_USER>@<SERVER_IP>/<SHARE_NAME>` (`smb://WORKGROUP\alldocube@192.168.0.5/D` in my case).

[Ref.: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/samba-client-and-windows-10-home/a7502032-240a-4fc8-a756-132d46831adf?tm=1568998388625&auth=1&page=2 ]

Thanks! =D